# 'or' operator inside switch PHP

Tags: php, comparison, switch-statement

Well, I think this is kinda weird but I would like to know if I can use the 'or' operator inside a switch something like this:

```
$pet = 'cat';

switch($pet)
    case 'cat' or 'Cat':
      echo 'Is a cat';
      break;
    case 'dog' or 'Dog':
      echo 'Is a dog';
      break;
    default:
      echo 'There is no pet';
      break;
  };
```

I tried it yesterday and somehow I think it worked, maybe, today I tried something similar but it didn't worked, I would like to know if there's a way to do something like this, and if there's a way to compare two values inside a case.

Thank's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a hundred percent sure as I didn't use PHP for a while, but you should be able to write something like that:

```
$pet = 'cat';

switch ($pet)
{
    case 'cat':
    case 'Cat':
      echo 'Is a cat';
      break;
    case 'dog':
    case 'Dog':
      echo 'Is a dog';
      break;
    default:
      echo 'There is no pet';
      break;
};
```

Alternatively, you can use a method like `strtolower($pet)` before you run the switch case, so that you only have to test one thing at a time.

```
$pet = 'cat';

$testedString = strtolower($pet);

switch ($testedString)
{
    case 'cat':
      echo 'Is a cat';
      break;
    case 'dog':
      echo 'Is a dog';
      break;
    default:
      echo 'There is no pet';
      break;
};
```

Comment: In this particular example, you could use strtolower(), too.

Comment: It worked perfectly like @duTr said. Thank's.

Comment: @bozdoz Thanks for the function name. I edited my answer

Comment: @duTr could you give me a better example of how to use strtolower() in this case?

Comment: @andres-orozco What do you mean? How to use the `strtolower()` function?

Comment: @duTr yeah, how to use it in this case, you said I could use it before the switch case, could you give me an example of how to use the strtolower() function instead of the double case?